# $(a_nx_n)_n\in \ell^q\ \forall x\in \ell^p\Rightarrow a\in \ell^r$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $1\le q<p<\infty$ and $a$ be a real sequence satisfying: $(a_nx_n)_n\in \ell^q\ \forall x\in \ell^p.$
I managed to prove that $M_a:\ell^p\rightarrow \ell^q,\ x\mapsto (a_nx_n)$ is a bounded linear operator but now I have to prove that $a\in \ell^r$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{q}$ and I don't know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation you have
\begin{equation} \tag{1}\frac{1}{\frac{p}{q}} + \frac{1}{\frac{r}{q}}=1\end{equation}

and
\begin{equation} \sum |a_i|^q |x_i|^q =  \sum |a_i x_i|^q < \infty; \; \text{ for each } x \in \ell^p. \end{equation}
which implies
\begin{equation} \tag{2} \sum |a_i|^q |x_i| < \infty; \; \text{ for each } x \in \ell^{p/q}. \end{equation}

Hence
\begin{equation} (|a_n|^q) \overset{(2)}{\in} (\ell^{p/q})^* \overset{(1)}{=} \ell^{r/q}. \implies (|a_n|) \in \ell^r. \end{equation}